# Evento CellClick dataGridView C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo una duda, realizo un proyecto en C# siguiendo un tutorial y en el evento de dar click a una celda se realiza el siguiente condicional el cual no entiendo su lógica

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == this.dataGridView1.Columns["Eli"].Index)
    {
        DialogResult result;
        result = MessageBox.Show("Realmente desea eliminar este usuario?", "Eliminando registro", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
    }
}
```

A lo que comprendo "e" es la variable que toma la celda a la cual se le dio click.
ColumnIndex es el index de la columna a la cual se le dio click, pero no comprendo lo demás, se comprueba en el condicional si `e.ColumnIndex` es igual a   `this.dataGridView1.Columns["Eli"].Index`
pero este ultimo no guarda exactamente siempre el mismo `index` que la variable e? no comprendo la diferencia o su utilidad exactamente en el código

Answer (score 0):

La variable "e" es una variable que te da la información sobre los [argumentos del evento](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcelleventargs?view=netframework-4.8) que se ha producido en la celda específica. Este [evento](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellclick?view=netframework-4.8) se va a ejecutar en todas las celdas de tu `DataGridView` por lo que sabiendo esto, toma lógica la comprobación que hay hecha en el `if`.

```
if (e.ColumnIndex == this.dataGridView1.Columns["Eli"].Index)
{
    DialogResult result;
    result = MessageBox.Show("Realmente desea eliminar este usuario?", "Eliminando registro", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
}
```

En este `if` se comprueba que la celda a la que se le ha dado click pertenece a la columna `"Eli"` porque lo que va a continuación sólo se debe ejecutar cuando se da click a alguna celda de esa columna específica. Si no pusieras esta comprovación, se ejecutaría el código con cada click que dieras en la `DataGridView`.